# Why the specific process by name is not in the List i created?

Tags: c#

I have this function that i check if the process is started and when its exited.
But im using on a breakpoint on the IF and the List Count is all the time 0.

And when im running the task amanager i see there bf3.exe *32
So whats wrong here ?

```
private void isProcessRunning()
{                
    Process[] proclist = Process.GetProcessesByName("bf3.exe");

    if (proclist.Length > 0)
    {
        Logger.Write("Battlefield 3 Started");
        alreadyRun = true;
    }
    else if (alreadyRun == true)
    {
        Logger.Write("Battlefield 3 Exited");
    }            
}
```

Comment: I would change this to get all processes, then inspect the list in the debugger and see what the bf3 entry actually looks like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx):

> The process name is a friendly name for the process, such as Outlook, **that does not include the .exe extension or the path**. GetProcessesByName is helpful for getting and manipulating all the processes that are associated with the same executable file. For example, you can pass an executable file name as the processName parameter, in order to shut down all the running instances of that executable file.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .exe. That appears to work for me.